# How to use sparktable in knitr with rmarkdown for PDF

Tags: r, knitr, sparktable

Just learned about `sparktable` and went over few documents about it. I was wondering if it can be used with `knitr` and `rmarkdown` to produce a PDF document that embed `sparktable`?

Also, I noticed `plotSparkTable()` used in many examples, but it does not exist in the latest version 1.0 and it does exist in 0.9. Is there a replacement `plotSparkTable()`?

Answer (score 3):

See ["sparkTable: Generating Graphical Tables for Websites and Documents with R"](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015-1/templ-kowarik-meindl.pdf) for examples of how to use `sparkTable` with `knitr`.  Here's an example from the article:

````
```{r , echo = TRUE }
require ( sparkTable )
sl <- newSparkLine ( values = rnorm (25) , lineWidth = .18 , pointWidth = .4 ,
width = .4 , height = .08)
export ( sl , outputType = " png " , filename = " sparkLine ")
```
This is a sparkline included in the ![ firstSparkLine ]( sparkLine . png )
text ...
````

`export()` is the replacement for `plotSparkTable()`

Comment: Is there an example of "export()" for newSparkTable with knitr and rmarkdown that embed an newSparkTable into a PDF?